# Is there a way to optimize this better?

Tags: kotlin

Is there a more optimized/efficient way to do this? Tried some things, this seems right, but better to know if there is a better way of doing this. This is for my discord bot, command called "8ball" where you ask bot a question, and he replies with random reply.

```kotlin
            val num = Random.nextInt(1, 9)
            var text = ""
            when (num) {
                1 -> text = "Yes"
                2 -> text = "No"
                3 -> text = "Maybe yes"
                4 -> text = "Maybe no"
                5 -> text = "I don't know"
                6 -> text = "Ask csskrouble"
                7 -> text = "Ask someone else"
                8 -> text = "Rather yes"
                9 -> text = "Rather no"
            }
```

Comment: You could create a dictionary out of this and randomly access a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just do:

```
    val text = when (Random.nextInt(1, 10)) {
        1 -> "Yes"
        2 -> "No"
        3 -> "Maybe yes"
        4 -> "Maybe no"
        5 -> "I don't know"
        6 -> "Ask csskrouble"
        7 -> "Ask someone else"
        8 -> "Rather yes"
        else -> "Rather no"
    }
```

Btw, in `Random.nextInt(from, to)`, `from` is inclusive, but `to` is exclusive, meaning that you will never get a result of `9` with `Random.nextInt(1, 9)`

And yes, [FreshD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3883569/freshd) is right, you could also just do:

```
val text = listOf("Yes", "No", "etc").random()
```

Comment: @csskrouble just so you know, it is customary to allow for a few hours (even 24) to give a chance to others from different time zones to come up with answers. They might be better than this one, they might not. And after that, you choose what seems the best for you, and accept it as an answer. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I’ve never heard of that custom. Once you get a satisfactory answer, it makes sense to accept it so others don’t waste time looking it over. You can always change the accepted answer if a better one comes along.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm guessing you probably know better than me. I was told this, with the premise that most people don't try to answer already accepted questions, so it is worth to way some time.

Comment: I guess it depends on the nature of the question. It is true that you will get fewer answers once you accept one because fewer people will look at the question. So if the question isn’t a binary solved/not-solved sort of question, you may benefit from waiting. And this question does fit that category.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `Set`, and ask for a random value:

```
setOf(
    "Yes",
    "No",
    "Maybe yes",
    "Maybe no",
    "I don't know",
    "Ask csskrouble",
    "Ask someone else",
    "Rather yes",
    "Rather no",
).random()
```

Comment: quick question, why a set and not a list? I'm looking at the code, and for a Set it accesses the same `.random` from `Collection` as in List. Genuinely curious if there is an advantage on that (except the lack of duplicates).

Comment: I just felt like Set was a better representation of the data, as order is not important, and duplicates are not desired. In general, retrieving an random element from a `Set` (or checking for membership) will be more efficient than a `List`.

Comment: Looking at the implementation of that `random` function though, it seems to pick a random number and for non-lists uses an iterator to fetch the item, so I'm not sure it'll be more efficient in this case! But I still think `Set` is a better representation of the data.